# How do you modify the HSV values (hsv[1], hsv[1], hsv[2])?

Tags: android, view, hsv

I have a class that extends View. The class is created in a fragment that contains a seekbar. 
Using the code below, I pass the seekbar value to the view class via `seekbar.setSatVal(value)`.

```
public void setSatValue(float value){
        mValue = value/100; //seekbar goes from 0 to 100
        setVal(mValue);
    }
```

I then get the RGB values from the bitmap I passed (not shown in code) and convert them to HSV values.

```
int mPixel = mBitmap.getPixel(1,1);

            hsv = new float[3];

            r = Color.red(mPixel);
            g = Color.blue(mPixel);
            b = Color.green(mPixel);

            Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv);
```

I know that I have to use `Color.HSVToColor` to convert HSV values back to color.

How do I modify the HSV values? hue: hsv[0], saturation: hsv[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html), value: hsv[2] I have read through the [color documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) and know the values each takes.

Comment: Maybe like any other array? `hsv[0] = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, this should work as I have implemented the same in Android -

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
Color.RGBToHSV(red,green,blue,hsv);
hsv[0]=hue; //hue 
hsv[1]=sat; //saturation 
hsv[2]=val; //brightness
```

`hue` `sat` and `val` can be any user defined or calculated values.